# How do I make a UILabel text to fade away after few seconds?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UILabe for my matching card game that writs "Good match!" for example if you have a match, and I want to make it disappear after notifying the user with the message.

What method do that? can I make it fad away..? thanks.

This is my updateUI method:

```
    -(void) updateUI {

    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.unplayble;
        if (card.unplayble) {
            cardButton.alpha = 0.1;
        }
        self.scoreCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];


        if (self.game.notification) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
                self.notificationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.game.notification];
                self.notificationLabel.alpha = 0;
            }];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Read the [core animation programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), that's how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fade away the label over two seconds. Change the `animateWithDuration:` to however long you want

```
if (self.game.notification == nil) {
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
self.notificationLabel.alpha = 0;
}];
}
```

If you want to change the text, try this (I can't test it right now, so it might not work)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
self.notificationLabel.text = @"text you want to change it to";
}];
```

And then, when you want to use the label again, you have to set the `self.notificationLabel.alpha` back to 1. So try

```
if (self.game.notification) {
self.notificationLabel.alpha = 1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
self.notificationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.game.notification];
self.notificationLabel.alpha = 0;
}];
}
```

Comment: it did help to change the state of the label, but i'm trying to change the text (nsstring) that in notification..since to get this string i used the self.notificationLabel.text..do you know what i mean..? @ ChrisLoonam

Comment: this will fade the text over a 2 second duration, not after 2 seconds.

Comment: @nielsbot that's what I meant. My bad.

Comment: almost working buddy! updated my updateUI method to the question...the first time it works good, so i can see the first message and than it's fading away, but in the next match i cant see the message..@ChrisLoonam

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that's possible. More than likely, you'll need to replace the UILabel with a NSView in Interface Builder and use the drawing functions contained therein to draw the text with transparency.

Comment: Whoops. Not too familiar with iOS, figured it would similiar to OS X. I don't know, maybe try adjusting it with Core Animation?